# XAMPP + virtual hosts + group shared folder

Tags: apache, permissions, xampp, virtual-hosts

I have folder which mount for all users which in group 'common' for sharing files
/home/.common/ mounted to /home/common by fstab

> bindfs#/home/.common    /home/common fuse    group=common,perms=g=rwx

I want to share sites folders too. I put sites to dir /home/common/Sites/
and made virtual host to those directories. But i'm having error on enter.

**on http://mysite/**

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the
>   directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
>   please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403

**in httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**in httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/common/Sites/mysite
    ServerName mysite
    ErrorLog /home/common/Sites/mysite/mysite.local-error_log
    CustomLog /home/common/Sites/mysite/mysite.local-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/common/Sites/mysecondsite
    ServerName mysecondsite
    ErrorLog /home/common/Sites/mysecondsite/mysecondsite.local-error_log
    CustomLog /home/common/Sites/mysecondsite/mysecondsite.local-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**in .local-error_log**

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Access denied: access to / denied
```

When i turn on vhosts - localhost returns error too. If turn off LH works good.
How to make this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problen was in permissions. I was need to change apache user and group in opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

Comment: what user do you set there?

Comment: Myown user name.
//User shara
//Group www
Here is my manual: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148165